# How to get the tenant id with the azure-devops-extension-api and azure-devops-extension-sdk?

Tags: azure, devops

I have a small problem. I'm trying to get the tanant id. I tried to use code below but can only get project id.

```
import * as SDK from "azure-devops-extension-sdk";
import { CommonServiceIds, IProjectPageService } from "azure-devops-extension-api";
const projectService = await SDK.getService<IProjectPageService>(CommonServiceIds.ProjectPageService);
const project = await projectService.getProject();
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find **`tenant ID`** in Domain property of below DevOps API call response regarding **Identities**:

```
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/identities?searchFilter=General&filterValue=<Azure AD username>&queryMembership=None&api-version=7.0
```

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via Postman and got below results***

To create new Personal access token (PAT), you can find below steps in your DevOps portal:

[image]

I generated one `PAT token` with **full access** for my DevOps organization like below:

[image]

When I ran below query including PAT token in Postman, I got **`tenant ID`** in response successfully like below:

```
GET vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/identities?searchFilter=General&filterValue=<Azure AD user UPN>&queryMembership=None&api-version=7.0
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in Azure DevOps portal and got same tenant ID like this:

[image]

**Reference:**   [IdentitySelf interface | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-devops-extension-api/identityself?view=azdevops-ext-latest#azure-devops-extension-api-identityself-domain)