# How to get ADO organization tenant ID using azure-devops-extension-api

Tags: devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

My DevOps extension is a tab in the build pipeline results page. I need to get the AAD tenant ID (if any) for the parent organization. I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75017252/how-to-get-the-tenant-id-with-the-azure-devops-extension-api-and-azure-devops-ex) but it uses a web service that can't be called from a browser due to CORS. I've also played the [API package](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-extension-api) without success -- for instance:

```
const identityService = SDK.getService<Identities.IVssIdentityService>(Identities.IdentityServiceIds.IdentityService)
const identity = (await identityService).searchIdentitiesAsync(user.name, ["user"], ["ims", "source"], "uid")
```

This is the closes thing I could find to the identities endpoint, but it returns only user details (very different from what the endpoint returns). I don't understand what some of the parameters do (such as options) so perhaps the answer is there.

In summary, I am looking for a straightforward way to obtain the tenant ID (or name) that backs the current organization.